# Can I Publish Multiple Files To Nexus From Gradle In One Go?

Tags: gradle, nexus

I am using a closed source vendor application that occasionally sends me updates of jars in a zip file.

I want to refer to the zip in the Gradle build, unzip it and publish all the jars within it to my Nexus repo. I am assuming that they all have the same GroupId and that the name and version can be inferred from the file name itself.

Whilst testing out my script, I would rather not publish to Nexus and have to delete lots of test artifacts so I am using a flatDir repo for now.

So far I have this

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

configurations {
  zipArchives
}

uploadResultArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      flatDir(dirs: 'mvn')
      pom.groupId = 'com.stackoverflow.example'
    }
  }
}

artifacts{
  zipArchives file: file('unzipdir/api-1.2.34.jar')
}
```

This suffers from multiple problems.

1. It requires me to manually add the files to the artifacts list
2. It creates a pom with dependencies from the rest of my project instead of a pom with no dependencies
3. I haven't parsed out the versionId yet
4. This solution looks like the versionId is going to be the same for all

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Publishing third-party modules isn't currently supported by Gradle. You'd have to come up with some custom solution. One option I'd investigate is to use Nexus' REST APIs. Another is to convince the vendor to share artifacts via a private repository.

Comment: Why dont you manually or in a script upload it to Nexus and then do extraction and such as part of the build where you need the files?

Comment: Also for testing you could just create a separate repository and delete things in there once you got it working.